# Solr DataImportHandler - Oracle Date - Daylight Savings

Tags: java, date, solr, dataimporthandler

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111517/getting-correct-time-from-oracle-date-in-solr-dataimporthandler) and the [answer I added](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13589395/1627613) (my code can be viewed there), I can correctly retrieve the right date from my Oracle DB. However, Solr seems to convert this based on daylight savings. For example, one of my dates on the DB is:

```
2011-09-30T 00:15:05Z
```

However, when inserted into Solr, it looks like:

```
2011-09-29T 23:15:05Z
```

i.e. minus one hour. As part of the workaround of my solution, I convert from `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP` to `java.sql.Date` using `dateValue()`. When I print this value from my DataImportHandler's ScriptTransformer, it looks to be still in the format I want. Therefore I don't think my conversion is doing anything strange. Only when I retrieve this document from Solr do I see it converted, e.g.:

```
<date name="STRT_DT">2011-09-29T23:15:05Z</date>
```

which makes me think Solr is factoring in the Daylight Savings hour.

**Is there any way to prevent Solr from converting the date and just leave it as is?**

Answer (score -1):

Solr stores all DateField values in UTC format. Solr is converting your value to UTC, not Daylight Savings time. There is not a way to change this behavior that I know of, short of creating your own custom Date Field type. Please see the [DateField API docs](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/schema/DateField.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks for responding. I should have mentioned in the question that not all of my dates are converted though. For example, a date from November:

    2012-11-08T 22:59:59Z

is identical on the DB and on Solr, which made me think about Daylight Savings. Wouldn't this date also be converted (and thus be -1 hour)?

Comment: I am not sure. Can you confirm that it is only effecting dates that fall during Daylight Savings Time?

Comment: Yep, it looks to be, for example:  
---  
2012-10-28 00:00:00 goes back  
2012-10-29 00:00:00 doesn't  
---  
2013-04-01 00:00:00 goes back  
2013-03-31 00:00:00 doesn't  
---  
2013-10-27 00:00:00 goes back  
2013-10-28 00:00:00 doesn't  
---  
These are all times that the clocks change in my timezome, which is:  
  
user.timezone = Europe/London  
  
according to Solr admin. My DB doesn't perform this conversion automatically which is where the problem lies (i.e. they aren't in sync).